# How to send POST to ThingSpeak?

Tags: http, post, get, arduino

How can I send a POST to ThingSpeak through [www.requestmaker.com](https://www.requestmaker.com)?

I'm using this:

```
POST /update HTTP/1.1
Host: api.thingspeak.com
Connection: close
X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\
Content-Length: 24
field1=34&field2=1
```

But I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 728
Connection: close
Status: 404 Not Found
X-Request-Id: 36c8113c-3671-4302-85fa-f3ecdba364dc
X-Runtime: 0.019035
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.57
Date: Mon, 19 Dec 2016 02:36:42 GMT
Server: nginx/1.9.3 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.57
```

Any solution?

Comment: Response is 404... Are you 1000% sure you have correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the right API key -- it's common to get zeros and the letter 'O' incorrect.  What API end point are you writing to?   You can get help on the ThingSpeak forum:  http://community.thingspeak.com/forum/